# MySQL выбор кодировки

Tags: mysql

Всем привет, написал парсер для телеграм, который парсит информацию о каналах и все сообщения в них.
Сначала у меня была кодировка utf8general_ci.
Но при парсинге выкидывало ошибку на некоторые символы, и посоветовали использовать более позднюю реализацию utf-8 - utf8mb4_bin.

Но со временем, ошибка стала появляться вновь, посоветуйте другую кодировку,

**Ошибка**

Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

**Проблемные тексты**

```
 ️ ️️️️
```

Также кидает ошибки на текст:

```
Prime Optimus     Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D\xF0\x9F...' for column 'message' at row 1
Raja              Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8C U...' for column 'message' at row 1
坠入爱河           Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x93\x8C b...' for column 'message' at row 1
Roma              Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x89\xF0\x9F...' for column 'message' at row 1
```

Comment: Приведите DDL схему Вашей таблицы.

Comment: Проблема просто в том, что вы в базе смешали кодировки utf8 и utf8mb4. Используйте ТОЛЬКО utf8mb4

Answer (score 1):

Для полной поддержки Unicode Вам нужно нечто вроде:

```
--- For each database:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
--- For each table:
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
--- For each column:
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
--- (Don’t blindly copy-paste this! The exact statement depends on
--- the column type, maximum length, and other properties.
--- The above line is just an example for a `VARCHAR` column.)
```

В этой статье все неплохо расписано: [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

Вот [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d79ae/3) с результатами моделирования.

Важно при вставке указать `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';`

А вот `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';` - указывать не надо

Comment: я изменил все текстовые поля на кодировку utf8mb4_unicode_ci, но у меня все равно пролетают ошибки Incorrent string value

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_ci это Collate, используется при сравнениях. При загрузке данных важен Character Set. Вы его установили на utf8mb4?

Comment: вы предлагаете отправлять 3 запроса после создания cursor7

Comment: cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4;") 

cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;") 

cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;")

Comment: Это можно указать при создании подключения к базе данных?

Comment: Это определяет канал доставки данных в базу, что тоже важно. Но сам текстовый столбец в таблице должен иметь CHARACTER SET utf8mb4. Смотрите пример кода в ответе. Возможно, вся таблица и вся база тоже должны иметь CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 - нужно промоделировать. Collation - недостаточно!

Comment: @danilshik, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа